# My html form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm a beginner, and I need some help with my assignment. I can't work out what I've done wrong. The label and submit button appear in html, but when I click on the submit button it doesn't validate the form.

My assignment is to produce a form to enter your name. Onsubmit a function to validate the name is called that will validate that the name cannot be blank and must be more than 6 characters.

```
<html>
   <head> 
   <body>
      <form name="myForm" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
         <p><label>First name &#40;required&#41; <input type="text" id="firstName" 
            autofocus="autofocus" /> </label></p>
      </form>
      <input type="submit" name="S1" value="Submit response" />
      <script>
         function validateForm(){
         var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName");
                     if (firstName.value.length<6){
                                 alert("Please enter your first name (6 characters or more)");
                                 firstName.focus();
                                 return false;
         }
                     alert("Thank you for your submission");
                     return true;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
   </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is broken: your first input field is inside your `<label>` and your submit button is outside the `<form>`. The browser might allow you to get away with this, or it might not, but you haven't explained the difficulty you're having.

Comment: `but when I click on the submit button it doesn't validate the form`
It seems like he did explain his difficulties, @HoboSapiens.

Comment: @HoboSapiens There's [nothing wrong](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) with placing an input inside a label

Answer (score 1):

Place submit button inside of form tag

```js
function validateForm() {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
    if (firstName.value.length < 6) {
        alert("Please enter your first name (6 characters or more)");
        firstName.focus();
        return false;
    }
    alert("Thank you for your submission");
    return true;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head> 
   <body>
      <form name="myForm" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
         <p><label>First name &#40;required&#41;<input type="text" id="firstName" 
            autofocus="autofocus" /> </label></p>
         <input type="submit" name="S1" value="Submit response" />
      </form>
   </body>
   </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you try to return a result to an event. Events do not accept any response. So try this;

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="myForm" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="validateForm()">
      <p>
        <label>First name &#40;required&#41;</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" autofocus="autofocus" />
      </p>
      <input type="submit" name="S1" value="Submit response" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function validateForm(){
        var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName");
        if (firstName.value.length<6){
          alert("Please enter your first name (6 characters or more)");
          firstName.focus();
          return false;
        }
        alert("Thank you for your submission");
        document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit()
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Besides that, you put your body in your head, this can cause trouble with some browsers.

Comment: "And you placed an input in an label tag, this is also incorrect." [No it's not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) `To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element`

Comment: @MLeFevre, I always learned and used it before an input, not around it. Guess I was a bit wrong then.

Comment: I had the same thoughts as you, but came across the way I said a while back. I guess quite a few people are unaware you can do it that way. I prefer doing it that way now, as you' don't have to specify a `for` for the label, or an `id` for the input if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is outside of form tag, that's why the onsubmit method is not gettting called.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in your code. Remember you have to put submit button under `<form></form>` tag.     And always put JS code in `<head></head>` section.

Find below code and try hope this will work for you.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
        function validateForm() {
          var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName");
          if (firstName.value.length < 6) {
             alert("Please enter your first name (6 characters or more)");
             firstName.focus();
             return false;
         }
         alert("Thank you for your submission");
         return true;
      }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form name="myForm" autocomplete="on" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
         <p><label>First name &#40;required&#41; <input type="text" id="firstName" 
            autofocus="autofocus" /> </label></p>
         <input type="submit" name="S1" value="Submit response" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```